# Equality of two arrays in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the easiest workaround to do the following in BigQuery?

```
SELECT [1,2,3] = [1,2,3]
```

That is, `arr1 = arr2`. I thought casting to `JSON` might be the simplest, but that may lose information on non-json types, for example `DATE '2014-01-01'` vs `'2014-01-01'` and potentially ordering.

```
SELECT to_json_string([date '2014-01-01']) = to_json_string(['2014-01-01'])
# true
```

Is there a reliable method to do this? One option might be to use the string [`FORMAT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#format_string) function:

```
SELECT FORMAT('%T', [date '2014-01-01']) = FORMAT('%T', ['2014-01-01'])
# false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is almost certainly going to involve unnesting these arrays and comparing them elementwise.

The precise implementation depends on the actual configuration of your data, but let's reduce it down to the simple case where you really are just comparing two known arrays.

Then

```sql
    SELECT
        element,
        offset,
      FROM
        UNNEST([1,2,3]) AS element
        WITH OFFSET AS offset
```

will yield the table

```
element | offset
----------------
   1    |   0   
   2    |   1   
   3    |   2
```

By using `WITH OFFSET` we maintain our sense of the order of the original array elements and can use this to join the two unnested arrays:

```sql
WITH a1 AS (
    SELECT el1, offset
      FROM UNNEST(array1) AS el1
      WITH OFFSET AS offset
),
a2 AS (
    SELECT el2, offset
      FROM UNNEST(array2) AS el2
      WITH OFFSET AS offset
)
    SELECT el1, el2
      FROM a1 FULL JOIN a2 USING(offset)
```

This gives you a two column table where the Nth row contains the Nth elements of each array.

This is all perfectly safe to use with arrays of different lengths - the `FULL JOIN` ensures that you will just have some `NULL` values in one of the columns if they are different lengths.

Now, you wanted a test for equality. Of course `el1 = el2` is enough to test that elementwise, but you want to know if the *whole thing* is equal. This requires aggregation, specifically using `LOGICAL_AND`:

```sql
WITH a1 AS (
    SELECT el1, offset
      FROM UNNEST(array1) AS el1
      WITH OFFSET AS offset
),
a2 AS (
    SELECT el2, offset
      FROM UNNEST(array2) AS el2
      WITH OFFSET AS offset
)
    SELECT
        LOGICAL_AND(el1 = el2) AS is_equal
      FROM
        a1 FULL JOIN a2 USING(offset)
```

This will return a single value, which will be `true` if the arrays are the same length and all the elements (in order) are exactly the same, and `false` otherwise.