# Comparing two arrays in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Postgres has a nice utility in that arrays can be compared directly. For example:

```
SELECT ARRAY[1,2] < ARRAY[1,3];
#  t
```

How could this behavior be emulated in BigQuery, for example with a function?

Comment: This is a near duplicate of a question last week, so [here is a link to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74791790/9044370), which I think may be more effective than the ones you've got so far. Let me know over there if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below hint

```
select format('%t', ARRAY[1,2]) < format('%t', ARRAY[1,3])
```

Comment: cool thank you, what's the difference between doing the string-compare vs the element-at-offset comparison, or do they both act the same?

Comment: this was just quick idea/hint to share as it looked compact. but obviously this is just the hint to consider as for example it does not work for ARRAY[1,21] < ARRAY[1,3]

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the offset of the arrays and then compare the value at that offset at the first difference. Here is an example:

```
WITH 
  a AS (SELECT * from UNNEST([1,2]) AS elem WITH OFFSET),
  b AS (SELECT * from UNNEST([1,3]) AS elem WITH OFFSET) 
SELECT 
    a.elem < b.elem 
FROM
    a JOIN b USING (offset)
WHERE
    a.elem != b.elem
LIMIT 1
```

[image]

Comment: I think adding `ORDER BY offset` would be more accurate since `LIMIT 1` doesn't guarantee the first non-equi result in the order of elements.